# Populate GridView: startManagingCursor(), and SimpleCursorAdapter have been deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have this method to populate GridView

```
private void populateGrid()
{

    GridView gv= (GridView)findViewById(R.id.mygrid);

    Cursor c = getData():
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] cols = new String[] { adap.ONE, adap.TWO, adap.THREE};
    int[]   views = new int[] { R.id.txt_1, R.id.txt_2, R.id.txt_3};

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.row, c, cols, views);

    Log.w("NumRows",adapter.getCount() + "");

    gv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Unfortunately the method

```
startManagingCursor(c);
```

And this constructor

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listviewtemp, c, cols, views);
```

have been deprecated since API level 11.

How should I rewrite this simple method avoiding the deprecation?

Comment: to which API your coding

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy API Level 17, however these are deprecated since API level 11

Comment: then try CursorLoader http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: could you give me a sample? thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/1217628 try this and before that just read the docs of CursorLoader

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate with **CursorLoader**.

This provides better performance than **cursoradapter**.

You can find the sample project in the below link which gets the list of apps installed in any phone.

https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader.git

Good luck..